# Detect/Correct Stitching in CODEX Images

Tags: image, image-processing, fft

detecting stitching artifacts in CODEX images can be challenging. I have CODEX Multiplex images where each image consists of multiple protein markers and each image is divided into smaller regions. Therefore, one patient has multiple markers and multiple regions. [IWP5 patient fluorescent intensity image for multiple markers and regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJIws.jpg) is a snapshot of one patient image. As you can see, some markers and some regions show a stitching effect(marked in red) which is problematic in downstream analysis.
I would like to know how can I detect and possibly correct the stitching effect. My current approach is to apply inverse Fourier transform on the intensity of these images per marker, per region to see if I can see a pattern. However, this method doesn't seem to be a good method for detecting stitching for all patients.
Are there any recommendations or alternative methods that can detect stitching? It would be best if you could help with suggesting stitch removal as well but the priority is with detecting the stitching.

I tried the Fourier and the inverse Fourier transform. I expected to see a spike in magnitude for the high-frequency component in stitched images. But, non-stitched images also show similar patterns.